# How to divide underline with ULEM package?

Tags: fonts, macros, errors

[image: in the pic, the underline is divided]

[image: I change the ulem package, and want to seperate some words, but chinese character can't be seperated.]

[image]

In some Chinese books, proper nouns were underlined uncontinuously. How to divide underline with ULEM package, as in the first pic? I changed the ulem package, and want to seperate some words, but chinese character can't be seperated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Preparing a minimal example, make sure not to use chinese charackters, most of us can't read them.

Comment: I guess you need to underline every instance separately. I guess one could work out something that works like the macros when documenting code -> `text and some |code|` That would save some time typing.

Comment: Please copy/paste the code into the site (ideally highlighting everything again and press `ctrl + k`). That way we can just copy/paste and test ourselves.

Comment: I would use TikZ to place a `\tikzmark` wherever you use something like `\insertgap` - where you want to break the horizontal rule. TikZ would then overlay a vertical, white rule.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to avoid the `ulem` package in this case and use the `xeCJKfntef` package instead.

The `xeCJKfntef` package is a descendant of the old `CCTfntef` and `CJKfntef`, and it is a part of the [`xeCJK`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) package. The `xeCJKfntef` package doesn't relay on the `ulem` package.

Li Qing, one of the current maintainer of `xeCJK`, fixed this problem last month. You may want to check the manual of `xeCJK` to see what had changed (about `xeCJKfntef`).

Here is an example for you.

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{ctexart}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xeCJKfntef}[2014/11/05]

\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}

\newcommand*\Book{\CJKunderwave-}
\newcommand*\Noun{\CJKunderline-}

\xeCJKsetup{underline/format}

\begin{document}

如上所述，\Book{中國文學史}原是\Noun{復旦大學出版社}出版的，\Book{中國文學史新著}則由\Noun{上海文藝出版社}出版。現承\Noun{復旦大學出版社}\Noun{賀聖遂}先生的盛情和\Noun{上海文藝出版總社}\Noun{楊益萍}、\Noun{何承偉}先生以及有關負責人\Noun{陳鳴華}先生的高誼，此書增訂本改由兩社聯合出版。\Noun{賀聖遂}先生並與\Noun{杜榮根}副社長、\Noun{韓結根}編審共同擔任此書的責任編輯。對上述諸位先生謹在這裡表示衷心的感謝。對\Book{中國文學史新著}原版的責任編輯\Noun{戴俊}先生（現為\Noun{上海三聯書店}副總經理）也在此一併致謝。

\Noun{與文學史的}\Noun{應有任務}\Noun{對文學發展過程}\Noun{的內在聯繫的描述}\Noun{還有很大的距離}\Noun{至於距離的所在}\Noun{本書原已有說明}\Book{此不贅述}\Book{為了對學術負責}\Book{我們決定重寫一部並迅即出版}

\Noun{南朝}\Noun{梁}\Noun{劉勰}\Book{文心雕龍}\Book{養氣}

\Noun{鎌池和馬}\Book{魔法禁書目錄}\Book{某科學的超電磁砲}

\Noun{西尾維新}\Book{化物語}\Book{偽物語}\Book{貓物語}%
\Book{傾物语}\Book{囤物語}\Book{鬼物語}\Book{戀物語}\Book{花物語}

\Noun{岡田麿里}\Book{我們仍未知道那天所看見的花的名字。}\Book{絕園的暴風雨}

\Noun{虚淵玄}\Book{Fate/Zero}\Book{PSYCHO-PASS}\Book{ALDNOAH.ZERO}

\Noun{劉海洋}\Book{\LaTeX 入門}

\def\NAME{%
  \x{御坂美琴}\x{白井黑子}\x{戰場原緋多木}\x{阿良良木歷}%
  \x{宿海仁太}\x{本間芽衣子}\x{瀧川吉野}\x{鎖部葉風}%
  \x{衛宮切嗣}\x{言峰綺禮}\x{常守朱}\x{狡嚙慎也}%
  \x{界塚伊奈帆}\x*{艾瑟依拉姆·沃斯·艾莉歐斯亞}}

\let\x\Noun\NAME

\let\x\Book\NAME

\end{document}
```

The output:

> [image]

Comment: Well done! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Here, I redefine `\uline` and `\uwave` to clip 1.5pt off of each end, which allows for a broken line/wave even for continuous characters.  The `\uwave` behavior was a bit tricky because it insists on placing an integer number of waves, so the tail end is not always precise.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ulem}
\let\svuline\uline
\let\svuwave\uwave
\def\uline#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\kern1.5pt\svuline{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\wd0-3pt\relax]{}}\kern1.5pt\kern-\wd0#1}
\def\uwave#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\svuwave{\makebox[\dimexpr\wd0-3pt\relax]{}}}%
  \kern1.5pt\box2\kern1.5pt\kern-\wd0#1}
\begin{document}
\uline{black}\uline{matter} blah \uwave{test}\uwave{case} blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using \setbox, There is a bug that underline can't be broken automatically when a new line begins.

Comment: @Marcus I'm not sure if it is a "bug," but it is true that boxed material can not break in the middle for a newline.  That certainly applies here.